# Why is my CSV file empty

Tags: php, forms, csv, email-attachments

so i have this php script that after the user inputs data into a form that data is collected and some it is put into a .csv file and then sent as an attachment to the user, but i can get the email to send with the attachment but the .csv file is always empty and i dont know why heres my code

```
function send_csv_mail($csvData, $body, $to, $subject, $from)
{
    $multipartSep = '-----' . md5(time()) . '-----';

    $headers = [
        "From: $from",
        "Reply-To: $from",
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$multipartSep\"",
    ];

    $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w');

    fputcsv($fp, ["Supplier Number", "Supplier Name", "Product Code", "Product Description", "Unit of Measure", "Product Group", "Buy Price EX GST"]);

    $testData = [
        ['123', '456', '789', '012', '345', '678', '901'],
        ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '123', '456', '789', '012'],
        ['jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', '123', '456', '789', '012'],
    ];

    foreach ($testData as $data) {

        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($fp)));

    $newBody = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859" . "\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$body" . "\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep" . "\r\n"
        . "Content-Type: text/csv" . "\r\n"
        . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n"
        . "Content-Disposition: attachment;             filename=\"New_Parts_and_Barcodes_Request.csv\"" . "\r\n"
        . "\r\n"
        . "$attachment" . "\r\n"
        . "--$multipartSep--";

    return @mail($to, $subject, $newBody, implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
```

sorry about my formatting first post :)

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` requires file path as argument, not a file pointer.
Try to change it into

`$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("php://temp")));`

Comment: Ok I have made the change you suggested, but still not getting the data through, any other ideas

Comment: Can you try to move `fclose($fp);` to the end of script?

Comment: fclose($fp) has been moved to just before the return at the end of the script. I tried it again but still no dice.